# PayPal sandbox subscription "Sorry, we couldn't set up your subscription using the payment method you've selected"

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

testing sandbox with normal PayPal buying / paying for product it's working well with a test credit card that I generate. But when I try to test for subscription, this error shows up.

"Sorry, we couldn't set up your subscription using the payment method you've selected. Please try another."

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&vault=true" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
<script>
  paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'blue',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'subscribe',
          
      },
      createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.subscription.create({
          'plan_id': 'P-xxxxxxxxxxx'
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        alert(data.subscriptionID);
      }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: How was the plan created

Comment: @PrestonPHX Hi, product and plan created using the UI in paypal website.

Comment: What are its details?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm having the same problem. @William

Comment: @William Did you figure it out? I'm in the same trouble.

Comment: @Mariana I have not yet, it's troublesome, but you can get help from PayPal support, basically they told me to process the payment while the chrome developer tool is opened up and give them the debug id https://imgur.com/LLS21qN  I have not replied them yet, I have used Stripe instead, it's so much easier and seamless and much better documented. Will come back to PayPal later if needed.

Comment: @William Thank's!!

Answer (score 2):

I think it has Something to do with setup_fee while creating the plan. when I set it null ,I get the same error as yours. But when i Give it some value, it works.

Let me know , if this Works For You.

Comment: I am getting the same error, using WooCommerce. I tried setting the setup fee to $1 and got the same error.

Comment: Dammm! this solved my issus! thanks